# PayPal Adaptive Payments and SOAP SDK

Tags: php, paypal

I'm integrating Adaptive Payments in a PHP application that already uses the PayPal SOAP SDK for MassPay.
Everything looks very simple the problem is when calling the MassPay integration it now has a name clash because CallerServices were already declared by the Adaptive Payments API.

Is there any easy (and good) way for those APIs to live together? How can I require both APIs if they declare objects with the same name?

I checked if both CallerServices.php files were the same but they aren't...

Error message:
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CallerServices in (...)/PayPal/CallerServices.php on line 35

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of PHP are you using? If >= 5.3, you will be able to resolve this by declaring a [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Comment: Thanks, we're using 5.2.13 and the project is out already but I'm marking as correct because it answers the question :)